# How to override template for drupal views attachment?

Tags: views, theming

The view that I am looking at is a 'page'. I have created an attachment. The theming suggestions for the attachment don't seem to be working.

I am perhaps confused as to whether the attachment takes on the theme namespace of the page or the attachment when rendered through the page.

The attachment reports that I should use views-view-unformatted--class-timetable.tpl.php and that this template is being used for the attachment.

[image]

When I view the page, this template is not being rendered. Using `$conf['theme_debug'] = true;` the templating engine reports that it is being rendered with sites/all/modules/contrib/views/theme/views-view.tpl.php.

[image]

In theory the unformatted name-spaced template should work for both the page and the attachment (the page is bvt tables, and the attachment is unformatted). What are the template names?

Comment: All you need is simple to copy and paste the code from one of the proposed templates by views to a file with one of the names proposed again by views and flush cashes, you over-complicating things. Remember to create that file in your theme's directory. A typical name of a template suggestion: `views-view--attachment.tpl.php,`

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  With the attachment it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: First check if you overriding the same template twice and then pick a more specific template name like: `views-view--my-view-machine-name--attachment.tpl.php`. Don't expect to see any difference in code, it's the same template as `views-view.tpl.php`.